# are derivatives useless for big incrementations?

Tags: derivatives

I know derivatives represent rate of change and such. What troubles me is that derivatives hold true for infinitesimal incrementations(dx) but not for bigger incrementations. In physics or in my area electrical engineering I see a lot of derivatives but I cannot really make sense of them. For example

```
  f(x) = x^2 + 1
 df(x) / dx = 2x
 f(3) = 10
 f(4) = 17
```

derivative at point 3 is 6 so this means if I go to right along x axis by 1, the change in y must be +6 but I see y becomes 17 which means change that occured is +7 instead of +6.

In physics or engineering we input big values into dx's but there seem to be no problem

Why is that?

Comment: It might help if you edited the part about “big values into dx’s” to give a specific example or two. I don’t recall any number being substituted for $dx$ in all the years I took physics or in any engineering papers I’ve read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the result of big changes by integrating the derivative.

$$ f(b) = f(a) + \int_a^b f'(t)\; dt $$

Comment: this is just like saying 2 = 2

Comment: @runo No, it's really quite a profound statement (there's a reason it's called the **Fundamental** theorem of calculus).

Answer (score 0):

You have that $f(4)-f(3)=7$, that is, the increment in the values of $f$ for going from $x=3$ to $x=4$ is $7$.

However $f'(3)=6$ means that the increment for the **tangent line** defined by the derivative at the point $(3,f(3))$ in the graph of $f$ is $6$. That is: derivatives measures the so-called "instantaneous change of rate at a point", this is the rate of change of the better local linear approximation to the function at a point.

Answer (score 0):

Taking more classes in EE or Math (Calculus at this point) would help you to understand the concept a lot better.

In short, your reasoning is not completely correct nor invalid.

> "derivative at point 3 is 6 so this means if I go to right along x
>   axis by 1, the change in y must be +6 but I see y becomes 17 which
>   means change that occurred is +7 instead of +6."

You wrote this but you should know that your function's derivative, as when you move from 3 to 4 also changes. If it didn't change then your functions value will be exactly the amount that you expect --"+6". This if-"derivative-didn't-change" assumption basically says that: "were your derivative a constant", which says that "were your original function linear" or look like a straight line when you plot it. Here your original function isn't.

I also commented that your argument isn't completely invalid. This is because using your logic, plug in numbers for bigger increments forms the extreme basis for approximation theory without you realizing it. You are basically saying that if I use a linear function to represent my function "locally", I should get a somewhat good enough approximation for my function itself. More specifically, this is in fact a class of "first order" methods used, sometimes even now in numerical calculations. If you want to understand more, I refer you to look at Taylor expansions and Locally Analytical Functions.

One could easily fall in to the trap of thinking something is not useful when not knowing enough about it. Derivatives are powerful tools. A lot of work are done yet there's still much yet known to us.